# Button in the Header Template of Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET repeater which contains grid view and a panel which contains save button.
the repeater displays grid and save button for each employee..

if there are 5 employees then 5 grids and 5 save button will be displayed.
Now i want to move the save button to Header.. in that case i'll have only one save button for all the grids..

if any grid is modified and i click the Save button, how can we know which grid is edited. 
pls help.

Comment: do you want to do something like this: http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/ListBinding (click me = save button)

Answer (score 0):

If the grids don't post back, i'm not sure it's possible to know which grid was edited. You could add an hidden field to the page (asp:HiddenField) and modify the value using javascript and then check the hidden value when the save button is pressed. Also, why do you have a save button? The gridview has full support for CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) operations.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use "for each" to loop throw all items in the repeater

and you can check if there is any change in the item then save it if not then leave it and move to the next item.